# Tensorflow Python OutofRange Error: Resource Exhausted

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am following the following Tensorflow Object Detection tutorial
[Tensorflow Object Detection](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JR8CmWyh2E8). I have downloaded the models from the following GitHub link [Object Models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research). I am trying to detect flowers using custom data. The `TFRecords` and the labels have all been created and as shown in the above tutorial when I run the `train.py` as 
`python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training\ --pipeline_config_path=training\ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config`.

I get the following error:

```
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.train.create_global_step
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:Summary name /clone_loss is illegal; using clone_loss instead.
2018-02-09 01:45:59.841297: I C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows\PY\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports    instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017/model.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Session.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoint to path training\model.ckpt
INFO:tensorflow:Starting Queues.
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError'>, OOM when allocating tensor with shape[24,1,3648,5472,3]
     [[Node: batch = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_STRING,  DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_INT64, DT_INT32, DT_INT64, DT_INT32, DT_INT64, DT_INT32, DT_BOOL, DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_STRING, DT_INT32, DT_STRING, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localho
 st/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](batch/padding_fifo_queue, batch/n)]]
 INFO:tensorflow:Caught OutOfRangeError. Stopping Training.
 INFO:tensorflow:Finished training! Saving model to disk.
 INFO:tensorflow:Recording summary at step 0.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "train.py", line 164, in <module>
 tf.app.run()
 File "C:\Users\ML\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages  \tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 48, in run
_sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
 File "train.py", line 160, in main
worker_job_name, is_chief, FLAGS.train_dir)
File "C:\Users\Ashwin\Desktop\game making\OpenCV\Tensorflow Object    Detection\models\research\object_detection\trainer.py", line 332, in train
saver=saver)
File "C:\Users\Ashwin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\slim\python\slim\learning.py", line 775, in train
sv.stop(threads, close_summary_writer=True)
File "C:\Users\Ashwin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\supervisor.py", line 792, in stop
stop_grace_period_secs=self._stop_grace_secs)
File "C:\Users\Ashwin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\coordinator.py", line 389, in join
six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)
File "C:\Users\Ashwin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\Ashwin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\queue_runner_impl.py", line 238, in _run
enqueue_callable()
File "C:\Users\Ashwin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1231, in _single_operation_run
target_list_as_strings, status, None)
File "C:\Users\Ashwin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when  allocating tensor with shape[24,1,3648,5472,3]
     [[Node: batch = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_STRING,  DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_INT64, DT_INT32, DT_INT64, DT_INT32, DT_INT64, DT_INT32, DT_BOOL, DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_STRING, DT_INT32, DT_STRING, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localho
 st/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](batch/padding_fifo_queue, batch/n)]]
```

These lines seem to indicate the nature of the error:
`INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError'>, OOM when allocating tensor with shape[24,1,3648,5472,3]
INFO:tensorflow:Caught **OutOfRangeError**. Stopping Training.`

I have looked at GitHub pages where removing the `num_epochs` seem to fix the `OutOfRange` error but I cannot find such parameters in the `train.py` downloaded from the repo. This is my very first outing with TensorFlow and am not able to understand the mechanics completely.

My dataset labels size is : 124 images in training labels and 93 images in test labels.

Comment: If you don't have enough memory on your GPU to fit the whole test data, you could feed it in small batches to the eval graph

Comment: I just wonder... 124 training images make your computer out of memory. How small it could be?

Comment: @Straw: Inter i7 2,4ghz and 8GB RAM, you wonder its small?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your `OOM` issue (acronym for **Out Of Memory**) is a knowed issue discussed on [Github issues of Tensorflow repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/136).

It seems that it is not always the same problem for everyone. I will try to enumerate the most popular solutions.

1. Reducing the batch size `batch_size` of your `.config` file. Take in mind that it will take significantly longer to process.
2. Free up the memory (RAM) on your machine. I don't know on which OS your are on but I guess
   a Linux distribution. [Here is a StackExchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87908/how-do-you-empty-the-buffers-and-cache-on-a-linux-system)

   on it.
3. [Making more checkpoint](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model), that mean save your trained model more often before it crashes and restore it there.

Of course, none of the solution here are optimal, the real solution being having a more powerful GPU at your disposal.

If you have access to it, you may also consider using the *cloud ressources* (the most popular being *AWS* and *Azure*) but it may be costly.

Comment: When I reduced the batch size from the default 24 to 10, it was terribly slow and was freezing up, but the error still persisted. I have changed the classes to 1 and  am using `ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets` config file. I am on a Windows machine with 8gb RAM and i7 2.4Ghz

Comment: Thank you for the acronym which pointed me in the right direction, I made a couple of changes in the config file like decreasing the queue capacity and reducing the batch size. This resulted in no errors and the training proceeded without any error albeit slowly

Answer (score 0):

If it's custom data, you'll have to use a custom config file (in particular you'll need to change the number of classes in it).

You'll also find `num_epochs` in there, as well as the batch sizes for training and testing (reducing it will reduce the risk of getting OOM errors). It looks like you're running on CPU, you need to make sure you have enough RAM on it to run your training. Otherwise you'll have to use a smaller network, but SSD on MobileNets is already very small so it won't be easy...

Comment: I have modified the config file and there were not many changes to be made. I changed the number of classes and the rest of the parameters were left as default. I used the `ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets` config file . I do have 8gb of RAM and is there anything else I should change or do? Reducing the batch size freezes my machine.